# Continuity of eigenvectors of self-adjoint matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, continuity, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

What I have here is a matrix function $A(x,y)$, defined on $[0,1]\times [0,1]$, such that each $A(x,y)$ is a self-adjoint positive semi-definite $n\times n$-matrix (with possibly complex entries). Moreover, $(x,y)\mapsto A(x,y)$ is supposed to be continuous on $\mathbb R^2$ and it has constant rank, i.e., the multiplicity of the zero eigenvalue is constant and all the other eigenvalues remain in an interval $[a,b]$, where $a > 0$. Can I then find continuous matrix functions $U$ and $B$ such that
$$
A(x,y) = U(x,y)B(x,y)U(x,y)^*,
$$
$U(x,y)$ is unitary, and $B(x,y)$ is block diagonal of the form
$$
B = \begin{pmatrix}0&0\\0&B_2\end{pmatrix},
$$
where $B_2(x,y)$ is a square matrix function of the size equal to the rank of $A(x,y)$?

Comment: https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0022123684900533?via%3Dihub

Comment: @fredgoodman Ok, thank you. So, as far as I understand, this is not necessarily possible because $\mathbb R^2$ is not sub-Stonean (actually, my domain is $[0,1]^2$, but which is neither sub-Stonean). Is this correct?

Comment: I didn't read the paper, so I can only say that the problem is not so straightforward, and to get general positive results one has to insist on a not very usual sort of space.  If you look more into the literature (starting with that paper) maybe you can find some straightforward counterexamples.  Please report back!

Comment: @fredgoodman Thanks for your reply. I searched the internet like stupid, but couldn't find nothing really helpful. Just a few examples. The problem is that in that paper they want diagonalizability for all normal matrices, whereas my matrix function is more special. I have now also edited my question respectively.

Answer (score 2):

No, you cannot (at least in the case where the matrix entries for $A$ and for $U$ and $B$ are all real).

I'm going to construct for you an example where $n = 2$, i.e., for each point $(x, y)$ of the plane, I'll build a $2 \times 2$ matrix with the right properties, and it'll be clear that $U$ and $B$ cannot be defined continuously.

First, $A(0,0) = I_2$, the identity. For all other $(x, y)$, $A(x, y)$ will *not* be the identity, and will have one eigenvalue that's greater than $1$, and another that's less than $1$ (in fact, their product will be $1$) and will be symmetric, so its two eigenvectors will be orthogonal. Thus to specify the matrix, I really only need to tell you (1) a unit dominant eigenvector $v$, and (2) the eigenvalue $s$ for $v$. Because then $A(x, y)$ will be 
$$
A(x, y) = \pmatrix{v & v^\perp} \pmatrix{s & 0 \\ 0 & 1/s}  \pmatrix {v^t \\ (v^t)^\perp}
$$
where if $v = \pmatrix{a \\ b}$, then $v^\perp = \pmatrix{-b \\ a}$.

Let's start with the dominant eigenvalue. At location $(x, y)$, it'll be 
$$
s(x, y) = \frac{1 + 2(x^2 + y^2)}{1 + (x^2 + y^2)}.
$$ 
For $(x, y)$ near the origin, this'll be roughly $1$; for $(x, y)$ distance from the origin, it'll be roughly $2$.

Finally, I need to tell you $v(x, y)$. Because $(x, y)$ is not the origin [I already told you that $A(0,0) = I_2$, right?], I'm going to say that $x, y$ has polar coordinates $(r, \theta)$, where $0 \le \theta < 2 \pi$ Now I'm going to define 
$$
v(x, y) = \pmatrix{\cos \frac{3 \theta}{2}  \\
\sin \frac{3 \theta}{2} }
$$

This is clearly a continuous function of $x, y$ away from the origin, except along the positive real axis. On the positive real axis, $v$ points to the right; just a tiny bit below the positive real axis, $v$ points (almost exactly) to the left. Despite this, as you can see in the formula I gave for $A$ above, changing the sign of $v$ doesn't influence $A$, so this "sign discontinuity" in $v$ still leads to a continuous definition of $A$.

I leave it to you to really verify that this is a problem case, but looking at the values of $U$ and $B$ on the unit circle will help. $B$ -- the diagonal matrix of eigenvalues ---  has to be continuous, and one of the eigenvalues is $3/2$ and the other is $2/3$, so $B$ has to be a constant matrix. Let's put the larger eigenvalue in the $(1,1)$ location.

Then $U(x,y)$ --- the orthogonal matrix of eigenvectors --  has a first column that has to be a unit eigenvector for $3/2$. For $(x, y) = (1,0)$, this is either $\pmatrix{1\\0}$ or $\pmatrix{-1\\0}$. Let's pick the first one. Then using that value to determine the value at nearby points of the unit circle (think "analytic continuation", more or less), we get the first column of $U$ turning $3/2$ times as we go around the unit circle. Clearly this cannot be made continuous on the positive real axis.

Comment: [@John Hughes](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/114036/john-hughes)  very nice.   Is there some invariant, some sort of winding number, that can be identified as the obstruction?

Comment: Well, in this example at least, there's a map from $S^1$ (the unit circle, or "any small enough circle around an umbilic point") to the $S^1$, taking the point $(x, y)$ to the first column of $B(x, y)$, which ends up being in $S^1$. You then need to compose this with the map $\theta \mapsto 2\theta$ to guarantee that it's actually a *loop* in $S^1$, hence you get a map from umbilic points (if they're isolated!) to $\pi_1(S^1)= \Bbb Z$, although I think only the mod-2 reduction of this constitutes an obstruction. There may be secondary obstructions as well. As for larger $n$...I have no idea.

Comment: I guess that means that (for surfaces with isolated umbilics), the obstruction lies in $H_1(S-U, { \pi_1(S, S-u) }),$ where $U$ is the set of umbilics, and the twisted coefficient bundle consists of the fundamental group around each umbilic point $u$ (or something like that). Oh....and I need a reduction mod 2 in there somewhere as well...

Comment: @JohnHughes Sorry, but I couldn’t understand your answer. I had to stop when you start talking about matrices B and D that you‘ve never defined before. What are these?

Comment: My mistake -- I was trying to use the words from the original question, but replaced "U" and "B" there with "B" and "D" in my comment. [I thought "B" for basis and "D" for "diagonal" rather than "U for orthogonal" and "B" for "eigenvalues". :)  ] I've gone back and edited (which makes the comments on obstructions above no longer make sense, but anyone who knows about obstructions can probably piece together what I was trying to say).

Comment: @JohnHughes Thanks. But why does D (should also be changed to B, I guess) have to be constant because at one point it has eigenvalues 3/2 and 2/3?

Comment: In my first version I had U and D. Since I now want D to be only block diagonal, I call it B.

Comment: Understood. In my example, however, the blocks are $1 times 1$, because the two eigenvalues are distinct. But I at least understand your naming convention now. ;)

Comment: To answer your question: $B$ is (in my case) a diagonal matrix with the eigenvalues on the diagonal. The eigenvalues, at all points of the circle, are $2/3$ and $3/2$, So $b_{11}(\theta)$, for $\theta$ a point of the circle, is a continuous (per the original problem) function into the discrete space $\{ 2/3, 3/2 \}$. Every continuous function from a connected space like $S^1$ to a discrete codomain is constant. QED.

Comment: @JohnHughes Ok, got that. But I still don’t get the overall argument. And, to be honest, I cannot accept your answer unless you give me an explicit matrix function for which this is not possible. Please also note that the unit norm vectors orthogonal to (a,b) in $\C^2$ are given by $e^{it}(-b,a)$. Also, I would like to have the eigenvalues to be apart from each other at all times (see my question).